# Generate classes from Json in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm currently learning flutter and trying to get some data from an API.

There is a class called `Series`. The class looks like this:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:movies_app/model/season.dart';

part 'series.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Series {
  int seriesId;
  String name;
  String backdrop;
  String poster;
  String overview;
  String firstAirDate;
  String lastAirDate;
  String homePage;
  bool inProduction;
  String originalLanguage;
  String originalName;
  int numberOfEpisodes;
  int numberOfSeasons;
  String status;
  String type;
  num vote;
  List<Season> seasons;

  Series(
      {required this.seriesId,
      required this.name,
      required this.backdrop,
      required this.poster,
      required this.overview,
      required this.firstAirDate,
      required this.lastAirDate,
      required this.homePage,
      required this.inProduction,
      required this.originalLanguage,
      required this.numberOfEpisodes,
      required this.numberOfSeasons,
      required this.status,
      required this.type,
      required this.vote,
      required this.originalName,
      required this.seasons});

  factory Series.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$SeriesFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SeriesToJson(this);
}
```

The generated file is the following:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'series.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Series _$SeriesFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Series(
    seriesId: json['id'] ?? -1,
    name: json['name'] ?? '',
    backdrop: (json['backdrop_path'] != null)
        ? 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780${json['backdrop_path']}'
        : '',
    poster: (json['poster_path'] != null)
        ? 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${json['poster_path']}'
        : '',
    overview: json['overview'] ?? '',
    firstAirDate: (json['first_air_date'] == null)
        ? ''
        : json['first_air_date'].toString().replaceAll('-', '/'),
    lastAirDate: (json['last_air_date'] == null)
        ? ''
        : json['last_air_date'].toString().replaceAll('-', '/'),
    homePage: json['homepage'] ?? '',
    inProduction: json['in_production'] ?? false,
    originalLanguage: json['original_language'] ?? '',
    numberOfEpisodes: json['number_of_episodes'] ?? -1,
    numberOfSeasons: json['number_of_seasons'] ?? -1,
    status: json['status'] ?? '',
    type: json['type'] ?? '',
    vote: json['vote_average'] ?? -1,
    originalName: json['original_name'] ?? '',
    seasons: json['seasons']??[]);

Map<String, dynamic> _$SeriesToJson(Series instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'seriesId': instance.seriesId,
      'name': instance.name,
      'backdrop': instance.backdrop,
      'poster': instance.poster,
      'overview': instance.overview,
      'firstAirDate': instance.firstAirDate,
      'lastAirDate': instance.lastAirDate,
      'homePage': instance.homePage,
      'inProduction': instance.inProduction,
      'originalLanguage': instance.originalLanguage,
      'originalName': instance.originalName,
      'numberOfEpisodes': instance.numberOfEpisodes,
      'numberOfSeasons': instance.numberOfSeasons,
      'status': instance.status,
      'type': instance.type,
      'vote': instance.vote
    };
```

The seasons will be always an empty list, because somehow the app receives null, even if there are data in the response and the seasons array is not empty.

```
"seasons": [
    {
      "air_date": "2010-12-05",
      "episode_count": 272,
      "id": 3627,
      "name": "Specials",
      "overview": "",
      "poster_path": "/kMTcwNRfFKCZ0O2OaBZS0nZ2AIe.jpg",
      "season_number": 0,
      "vote_average": 0
    },
    {
      "air_date": "2011-04-17",
      "episode_count": 10,
      "id": 3624,
      "name": "Season 1",
      "overview": "Trouble is brewing in the Seven Kingdoms of Westeros. For the driven inhabitants of this visionary world, control of Westeros' Iron Throne holds the lure of great power. But in a land where the seasons can last a lifetime, winter is coming...and beyond the Great Wall that protects them, an ancient evil has returned. In Season One, the story centers on three primary areas: the Stark and the Lannister families, whose designs on controlling the throne threaten a tenuous peace; the dragon princess Daenerys, heir to the former dynasty, who waits just over the Narrow Sea with her malevolent brother Viserys; and the Great Wall--a massive barrier of ice where a forgotten danger is stirring.",
      "poster_path": "/wgfKiqzuMrFIkU1M68DDDY8kGC1.jpg",
      "season_number": 1,
      "vote_average": 8.3
    }]
```

Is there any way to fill the seasons list with the response above?

Comment: is `Season` class serializable?

Comment: Yes, it is seriezable

Comment: Probably "seasons": json['seasons']??[] is not enough due to the complexity of json['seasons'] string and you need to parse this in another way calling 'fromJson' also for creating the seasons' list